# How Can I return second element of stack without pop() function in C++?

Tags: c++, data-structures, stack

I need help for return second element of stack without pop() ? but I don't know how can I use.

my code :

```
stack<int> st;
st.push(10);
st.push(20);
st.top(); // return 20
```

How do can I make this function is return 10 without pop();

Thanks.

P.S. sorry for my English.

Comment: Not being able to use pop() is kind of a weird, artificial restriction.  If this is a homework or interview question, I think you've left something out, because there's no solution based on what you've posted so far.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I presume you're trying to emulate a stack-based machine?

Here's the only way to do it with std::stack:

```
stack<int> st;
st.push(10);
st.push(20);
int top = st.top(); // return 20
st.pop();
int second = st.top(); // return 10
st.push(top);
```

If you want other behavior you'll have to do your own implementation of `stack` that has more capabilities.

Answer (score 4):

You can not do that with `stack`, as it is supposed to be LIFO, if you want such a behavior use other sequential containers such as `vector`, `deque` or `list`.

Comment: Agreed, he should just use vector.  Methods push_back and pop_back are useful to emulate a stack, + he can do a bunch of other useful things. I don't even know why the standard is polluted with the existence of std::stack.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to retrieve the second element, why do you need `stack` as representation? The stack is a LIFO representation, so theoretically you don't retrieve *second element*, just the last one added.

Use other representation, such as @Naveen mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

If you do that, it will no longer be a stack, by definition.

Comment: No one would argue that processors don't have stacks, yet you can access any element of the processor stack at any time (on most popular architectures).